# Weird Video Found In My Phone

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, samsung, video, gallery

I have an old Samsung Galaxy Ace Duos (GT-S6802) running Android Gingerbread, it is a very laggy phone but I still use it to listen to Music. I got to the Gallery app (system app) and there was a video in a folder Titled: ap_video but when I go   to the video's details it says "Title: ad_video" and it's not a typo, the video is "ad_video" but the folder is "ap_video". In the video there is a woman Saying:

> They say behind every succesful man there is a woman; Hi I'm Sarah Markel 
>   and I believe... you just found that woman, because I'm about to stay behind YOU, yes, yes and guide YOU; Until every last one of you is making that kind of money.
>   Do it, do it now and I promise it will be the most important move you've ever done. (Then there is a black screen saying, "Please complete to the next step") END OF VIDEO.

But I really am a man and I don't have anything to do with business and money and stuff she is talking about in the video. I know some videos can go as an ad in a app. But the last app I installed was 'Retro Arch' which is uninstalled  and I didn't saw any ads in the app. There was not a long time since I opened my Gallery but last time I saw that folder "ap_video" and that video titled "ad_video".

Comment: Just delete it already. End of the story. We can't really know what apps did you try in that old phone of yours, how many of them might have placed files in the SD card and which one tried to be funny to place that video, at some point of their lifetime. It's not worth digging. And this is just my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was most likely an add video from an app. I find weird videos and pictures on my phone all the time and then later find out they go to an app. If you delete it, you will be fine. If it was important (probably not) the google store will re-download it. I don't think you have any reason to get worried about a virus.

As a side note, Sarah Markel appeared in a video add for quickcash(you most likely have that add), which is some sort of scam.

Comment: Anything new and useful you're keeping? Please mention it because the info you've mentioned is something we know already: that the video was most likely placed as an ad. We also know we can consider deleting it. What's worth knowing is what created that file at first place.

Comment: The useful info was that if the video was somehow important, google play will redownload it and he will be fine. I also confirmed that it was an add in my edit by showing that quickcash used Sarah Markel in their adds. I also added that it is very unlikely to be connected to some sort of virus or problem with his phone and he has no need to worry about it.

Comment: There are no viruses for Android but other kind of malwares. Regardless of who is featured in the video, the existence of the video itself is suspicious to begin with if OP doesn't remember owning or transferring it into phone. If it is not a malware, then what other issue can it really cause? Tell me? I (as a user) expect technical details in an answer. No speculation, no opinions.